# React Responsive Carousel not displaying images properly when iterating over more than 6 images

Tags: reactjs, typescript, carousel

I'm currently using the react-responsive-carousel library to display a carousel of images in my React application. The carousel works fine when I iterate over a small number of images, but when I try to iterate over more than 6 images, the carousel doesn't display the images properly. It either shows only one image or doesn't show any images at all. I had the same problem with react-slick. I can see in devtools in the browser that all the pictures are there.

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css';
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';
import { ImageGalleryBlockViewModel } from '../../types/blocks/ImageGalleryBlock/ImageGalleryBlockViewModel';

interface ImageGalleryCardProps {
  model: ImageGalleryBlockViewModel;
}

const ImageGalleryCard: React.FC<ImageGalleryCardProps> = ({ model }) => (
  <div>
    <Carousel>
      {model.imageUrls.map((imageUrl, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <img alt="hee" src={imageUrl} />
          <p className="legend">{`Legend ${index + 1}`}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </Carousel>
  </div>
);

export default ImageGalleryCard;
```

I suspect that the issue is related to how the carousel handles a large number of images being rendered dynamically. Can anyone suggest a solution or provide guidance on how to troubleshoot this issue? Thank you in advance!

Reducing the amount of images to 6 or less fixes the issue but i would like to be able to show about 300 images in a slideshow.